# Slice multiple column ranges with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

Suppose I have 20 Columns in a data set and i want to use 19 as an input. and input columns are columns from 1:10 and 12: 20. and I want to use 11th column as an output. so how to give this kind of range using pandas?

for example:
[Example Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfu6u.png)

consider above data it have 4 columns but i have to take input only 3 columns but those columns are b,d,e and i want to skip c column. Right now i m using 
input  = dftrain.loc[:,**:'e'**]
which consider all 4 columns.

Comment: Please paste your code so that one can suggest the solution according to the column names and your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
`np.r_`

```
idx = np.r_[0:11, 12:20]

idx
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
       18, 19])
```

Pass this to `iloc` -

```
df.iloc[:, 11] = df.iloc[:, idx].sum(axis=1) # sum, for example
```

---

**Option 2**
`pd.IndexSlice`

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice[0:11, 12:20]

idx
(slice(0, 11, None), slice(12, 20, None))
```

You can use `idx` in the same manner as before.