# Pandas dataframe slicing with multiple column ranges

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with many labeled columns. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

cols = ['lat', 'long', 'foo', 'bar', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'min', 'sec']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10, 10)), columns=cols)
```

I would like to slice this dataframe with multiple ranges. For example:

```
df.loc[:, ('lat':'long', 'year':'day')]
```

but it doesn't seem like this is possible. Is there any way to do this?

This issue is related to [Slice multiple column ranges with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47966085/5828163) and [Pandas Dataframe select multiple discontinuous columns/slices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50143469/5828163), but I want to slice with column names, not indices. `np.r_` doesn't seem to support string ranges, only numeric ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slicing by multiple label ranges is more challenging and has less support, so let's try to slice on index ranges instead:

```
loc = df.columns.get_loc
df.iloc[:, np.r_[loc('lat'):loc('long')+1, loc('year'):loc('day')+1]] 

        lat      long      year     month       day
0  0.218559  0.418508  0.345499  0.166776  0.878559
1  0.572760  0.898007  0.702427  0.386477  0.694439
2  0.803740  0.983359  0.945517  0.649540  0.860832
3  0.873401  0.906277  0.463535  0.610538  0.496282
4  0.187359  0.687674  0.039455  0.647117  0.638054
5  0.169531  0.794548  0.352917  0.484498  0.697736
6  0.022867  0.375123  0.444112  0.498140  0.414346
7  0.729086  0.415919  0.430047  0.734766  0.556216
8  0.138769  0.614932  0.109311  0.539576  0.289299
9  0.037969  0.500108  0.758036  0.262273  0.100859
```

When indexing by position I need to add `+1` to the right index since it is right-exclusive.

---

Another option is to slice individual sections and concatenate:

```
ranges = [('lat', 'long'), ('year', 'day')]
pd.concat([df.loc[:, i:j] for i, j in ranges], axis=1)

        lat      long      year     month       day
0  0.218559  0.418508  0.345499  0.166776  0.878559
1  0.572760  0.898007  0.702427  0.386477  0.694439
2  0.803740  0.983359  0.945517  0.649540  0.860832
3  0.873401  0.906277  0.463535  0.610538  0.496282
4  0.187359  0.687674  0.039455  0.647117  0.638054
5  0.169531  0.794548  0.352917  0.484498  0.697736
6  0.022867  0.375123  0.444112  0.498140  0.414346
7  0.729086  0.415919  0.430047  0.734766  0.556216
8  0.138769  0.614932  0.109311  0.539576  0.289299
9  0.037969  0.500108  0.758036  0.262273  0.100859
```